# Como somar números contíguos de um array?

Tags: java, array

Tenho um `array` de números que está sendo digitado pelo usuário, e preciso somar os números desse `array`.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Questao3 {
/*3.Fazer um algoritmo que:
•Leia um número indeterminado de linhas contendo cada uma a idade de um indivíduo.
•A última linha que não entrará nos cálculos, contém o valor da idade igual a zero.
•Calcule e escreva a idade média deste grupo de indivíduos.
•Escreva também a maior idade e a menor*/
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList <Integer> lista = new ArrayList<>();
        int soma = 0;

        System.out.println("Digite 0 para terminar");

        for (int i = 0; i < 10;) {
            System.out.print("Digiten um número: ");
            int num1 = s.nextInt(); 
                if(num1 == 0){break;}
            lista.add(num1);
        }
        for (Integer integer : lista) {
            System.out.print(integer);
        }
        int tamanho = lista.size();
        System.out.println(tamanho);
    }
}
```

Comment: Você pode se aproveitar do seu looping que exibe os números, basta adicionar `soma += integer;`

Comment: @Oeslei também pensei nisso, seria melhor logicamente mas se for considerar a pergunta essa solução não estaria somando os elementos do *array*.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 6):

Vá somando conforme vai recebendo os dados.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<>();
        int soma = 0;
        int menor = 999;
        int maior = 0;
        System.out.println("Digite 0 para terminar");
        for (;;) {
            System.out.println("Digite um número: ");
            int num = s.nextInt(); 
            if (num == 0) break;
            lista.add(num);
            soma += num;
            maior = Math.max(maior, num);
            menor = Math.min( menor, num);
        }
        for (Integer integer : lista) System.out.println(integer);
        System.out.println("A média de idade é " + (soma / lista.size()));
        System.out.println("A maior idade é " + maior);
        System.out.println("A menor idade é " + menor);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ZSzCwv). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/evsuhdfr-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Array/SumContinuesNumber.java).

Answer (score 4):

Antes de tratar da somatória, acredito que a sua lógica esteja errada. O enunciado diz que a entrada será um numero indeterminado de valores e seu *loop* vai de 0 até 9.

Para somar todos os índices basta fazer um loop de 0 até o tamanho desse *array* e utilizar o método `get(int index)` para pegar o elemento pelo índice. Exemplo:

```
for(int i = 0; i < meuArrayList.size(); i++)
    soma += meuArrayList.get(i);
```

Ou simplismente:

```
for(int idade : meuArrayList)
    soma += idade;
```

---

No exercício em questão você precisaria de dois *loops*, um infinito e outro que toma como condição de parada o tamanho do `ArrayList`.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SomandoArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Integer> idades = new ArrayList<>();

        int idade;

        /* Loop para inserir 'n' elementos no array */
        System.out.println("Digite 0 para terminar");
        for(;;){
            System.out.println("Digite um número: ");
            if((idade = input.nextInt()) == 0)
                break;
            idades.add(idade);
        }

        int totalIndividuos = idades.size();
        if(totalIndividuos > 0){

            int soma = 0, maior, menor;
            maior = menor = idades.get(0); 

            /* Loop para somar e encontrar a maior/menor idade */
            for(int _idade : idades){
                soma += _idade;
                if(_idade > maior) maior = _idade;
                if(_idade < menor) menor = _idade;
            }

            System.out.println("Media: " + soma/totalIndividuos);
            System.out.println("Maior: " + maior + " - Menor: " + menor);
        }  
    }
}
```

Eu tinha proposto uma sugestão sem o uso de `ArrayList` [anteriormente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/46157/revisions) (semelhante a [resposta do Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/46140/4808).

Answer (score 0):

Se tiver usando java 8 e quiser fazer com Lambda

```
        System.out.println("Media: " + lista.stream().mapToInt(r -> r).sum()/lista.size());
        System.out.println("Maior: " + lista.stream().mapToInt(r -> r).max().getAsInt());
        System.out.println("Menor: " + lista.stream().mapToInt(r -> r).min().getAsInt());
```